# iOS - Allow my app's users to take payment from their own customers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, stripe-payments, square

I currently have an app that allows users to manage their customers. That said, I want my app's users to be able to take payment from their own customers, and have the funds deposit to their own bank accounts. Does anyone know if Stripe, Paypal, or Square has an SDK that would allow users to login to their own payment accounts to take payment? Any help and/or tips are super appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

For PayPal, use a regular [Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) (Web JS SDK, Native SDK, and/or server-side REST API integration, as desired) and when creating the order specify a `payee` object with an email_address or merchant_id that is to receive the payment

See [the documentation for details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/).

Comment: Amazing, I'll give this a try this afternoon and report back! Thanks so much for the info :)